# Open Trip Planner API problem

Tags: opentripplanner

I've setup OTP on my windows machine and fed it the GTFS and OSM for Berlin. Now when I try to access localhost:8080/OTP/routers/default/plan?fromPlace

I get this error:

> we're sorry. the trip planner is temporarily unavailable. please try again later.","message":"system_error"

I'm using version 2.3.0

What can be the issue?